# MikTeX compilation failing

Tags: miktex

I've got a following problem with my MikTeX:
It is set up for CI in a docker container that runs a weekly build. Up until last week it was working perfectly fine, but now it is failing (no changes to the environment or target file were made). After digging through logs, most specific error message I could find is from `miktex-makefmt.log`:

```
2023-11-28 13:39:03,070Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - this process (8153) started by 'initexmf' with command line: miktex-makefmt --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2023-11-28 13:39:03,071Z WARN  miktex-makefmt - security risk: running with elevated privileges
2023-11-28 13:39:03,072Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - installing package miktex-latex triggered by tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini
2023-11-28 13:39:03,073Z INFO  miktex-makefmt.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/hello
2023-11-28 13:39:03,424Z INFO  miktex-makefmt.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/repositories?&releaseState=Stable&orderBy=ranking&take=1&onlySecure=true
2023-11-28 13:39:03,490Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2023-11-28 13:39:03,490Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: installation directory: /root/.miktex/texmfs/install
2023-11-28 13:39:03,490Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: package repository: https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2023-11-28 13:39:03,756Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: visiting repository https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2023-11-28 13:39:03,756Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: repository type: remote package repository
2023-11-28 13:39:03,756Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: loading package repository manifest...
2023-11-28 13:39:03,756Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: downloading https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2023-11-28 13:39:03,757Z INFO  miktex-makefmt.packagemanager - going to download https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma
2023-11-28 13:39:04,382Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: 0.34 MB, 120.53 Mbit/s
2023-11-28 13:39:04,508Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: package repository digest: eb93a288a00e139dd41badad530d38e9
2023-11-28 13:39:04,508Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: going to download 932 bytes
2023-11-28 13:39:04,508Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: going to install 4 file(s) (1 package(s))
2023-11-28 13:39:04,508Z INFO  miktex-makefmt.packagemanager - installing package miktex-latex
2023-11-28 13:39:04,508Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: downloading https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
2023-11-28 13:39:04,508Z INFO  miktex-makefmt.packagemanager - going to download https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-latex.tar.lzma
2023-11-28 13:39:04,575Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: 0.00 MB, 18.23 Mbit/s
2023-11-28 13:39:04,575Z INFO  miktex-makefmt - mpm: extracting files from miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
2023-11-28 13:39:04,629Z INFO  miktex-makefmt.core - forking...
2023-11-28 13:39:04,630Z INFO  miktex-makefmt.core - execv: "/usr/bin/initexmf", [ "initexmf", "--mkmaps" ]
2023-11-28 13:39:05,226Z FATAL miktex-makefmt.core - The installed file does not exist.
2023-11-28 13:39:05,226Z FATAL miktex-makefmt.core - Data: fileName="/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2023-11-28 13:39:05,226Z FATAL miktex-makefmt.core - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/Core/Session/findfile.cpp:61
2023-11-28 13:39:05,226Z FATAL miktex-makefmt - The installed file does not exist.
2023-11-28 13:39:05,226Z FATAL miktex-makefmt - Info: fileName="/root/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini"
2023-11-28 13:39:05,226Z FATAL miktex-makefmt - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/Core/Session/findfile.cpp
2023-11-28 13:39:05,226Z FATAL miktex-makefmt - Line: 61
```

I've tried updating apt packages, and it is **sometimes** working, but more often than not it is not. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this error?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the location of pdflatex.ini has changed in miktex. It takes them now from `tex/latex/tex-ini-files/pdflatex.ini` and not `tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.ini` but it looks as if the run above still looks in the old folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer any idea how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: no sorry I don't understand your setup and don't know what is new and what is fixed and old. If you updated the packages I would have expected that your script also updates the file name database.  Perhaps it is simply a temporary problem and a different repo or a new update repairs it.